# The color of a button, event listeners with a common object instance

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm
trying to add functionality similar to the CSS pseudo-class "Active", but in vanilla JavaScript. I'm trying to change the color of a button when pressed, then restore the original color when the button is released. Here's what I have:

```
myButton.addEventListener("mousedown", btnEvent);
myButton.addEventListener("mouseup", btnEvent);

...

btnEvent = function (e) {
    var storedColor;
    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        storedColor= e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = someColorWhilePressed;
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseup') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = storedColor;
    };
};
```

This doesn't work, upon `mouseup`, `storedColor` is undefined. I assume it's because the same function object is not shared but two are created? How can this be done? Is it possible for two or more event listeners attached to the same element to share a common target object (function) which can persist data between calls?

Answer (score 0):

Your variant does not work because `storedColor` is local variable and it is created every time `btnEvent` function is called.

You may store color in `btnEvent` function, because functions are objects in JavaScript.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LQSe4/

```
var btnEvent = function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        btnEvent['storedColor'] = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = someColorWhilePressed;
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseup') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = btnEvent['storedColor'];
    };
};

myButton.addEventListener("mousedown", btnEvent);
myButton.addEventListener("mouseup", btnEvent);
```

Or you may store original color in DOM element (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rk33f/):

```
var btnEvent = function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        e.target['storedColor'] = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseup') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = e.target['storedColor'];
    };
};

var myButton = document.getElementById('btn');

myButton.addEventListener("mousedown", btnEvent);
myButton.addEventListener("mouseup", btnEvent);​
```

Comment: It's ***much*** more useful to also explain what you changed, and why.

Comment: Storing the color on the function object is a **very** bad idea. Suppose you want to use the same function for more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, where it's specific to an element, you're probably best storing the color on the element itself:

```
btnEvent = function (e) {
    var elm = e.target,
        color;

    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
        elm.setAttribute("data-storedColor", e.target.style.backgroundColor);
        elm.style.backgroundColor = someColorWhilePressed;
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseup') {
        color = elm.getAttribute("data-storedColor"):
        if (color) {
            elm.style.backgroundColor = color;
            elm.removeAttribute("data-storedColor");
        }
    };
};
```

There, we're storing the color on a [data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). You could also just use an "expando" property (an ad hoc property you assign to the element, e.g. `elm.mySpecialProperty = ...`), but expandos generally aren't best practice.

---

Side notes:

- Unless you're declaring the `btnEvent` variable somewhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Either put a `var` in front of it, or better yet, make it a function *declaration* rather than an expression:

  ```
  function btnEvent(e) {
      // ...implementation...
  }
  ```
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) has a third argument, which you should probably supply. I seem to recall that some browsers are fussy about it (although any modern one probably isn't). (You'd want the value `false`.)